# Why do I have competing javac memory arguments when I run maven within IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA 12, I have a maven 2.2.1 run/debug configuration.  Under the "Runner" tab, I've specified the VM Options to be `-XX:MaxPermSize=768m -Xmx768m -Xms256m`.  When I run, the console shows:

```
C:\dev\sdks\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java -XX:MaxPermSize=768m -Xmx768m -Xms256m -Xmx1500M -XX:MaxPermSize=1500m -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\dev\bin\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.home=C:\dev\bin\apache-maven-2.2.1 -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\bin"...
```

Where is the extra set of options coming from (`-Xmx1500M -XX:MaxPermSize=1500m`)?

Comment: Have you checked if you have anything set up under File -> settings -> Maven -> Runner -> VM Options?

Comment: No, nothing is set there. +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: Anything in `Settings` | `Maven` | `Importing` | `VM options for importer`?

Comment: Any chance that you have `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Yes, but that has -Xmx512m, so that isn't the culprit.  +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: @kc2001 , MAVEN_OPTS environment variable inside IDEA process is "-Xmx1500M -XX:MaxPermSize=1500m". May be you had changed it but didn't restart the IDEA process. You can se how to IDEA creates VM options here: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/123/plugins/maven/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/idea/maven/execution/MavenExternalParameters.java   see 'addVMParameters()' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Xmx1500M -XX:MaxPermSize=1500m comes from MAVEN_OPTS environment variable.
It's a bug, options from MAVEN_OPTS should be before options from Runner tab (see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101087)